# UnsatisfiedLinkError while loading a native linux library in OSGi

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, osgi, raspberry-pi, equinox

Our team tries to bundle the [pi4j](http://pi4j.com/)-lib as OSGi bundle to access GPIO's on a Raspberry Pi but we getting a `UnsatisfiedLinkError` and don't know what is happening here and how to solve it.

We put the native `libpi4j.so` in the folder `/lib` of the bundle, and specified the `MANIFEST.MF` like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Pi4j
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.pi4j
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
Bundle-Vendor: http://pi4j.com/
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Bundle-NativeCode: lib/libpi4j.so; osname=linux;processor=arm
Eclipse-PlatformFilter: (& (osgi.os=linux) (osgi.arch=arm))
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/, .
Export-Package: com.pi4j.concurrent,[.. some more packages]
```

This is the Error-Message:

```
!SESSION 2013-02-10 08:21:25.975 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_40
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=arm, WS=gtk, NL=de_DE

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-02-10 08:21:37.256
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libpi4j in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1878)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1087)
    at com.pi4j.util.NativeLibraryUser.<clinit>(NativeLibraryUser.java:36)
    at eu.gemtec.carepi.app.Application.start(Application.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
```

The Class `NativeLibraryUser` has a call to `System.loadLibrary("libpi4j")` to load the native. The native is present in `/lib`-folder of the bundle so that should be no be the problem. What is happening here, why does it not work?

If I remember right, equinox unpacks the native to the bundle pool in order to load it, but i cant find one for our application, is that a problem?

Comment: Try calling just 'System.loadLibrary("pi4j")'. The lib prefix and .so suffix are added automatically.

Comment: That is the solution! If you create an answer, i will accept it. Can you provide a list of the naming scheme that is uses for other platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `System.loadLibrary("pi4j")`. The `lib` prefix and `.so` suffix are added automatically as part of the mapping provided by the JVM.

For example on most UNIX systems the above call will load `libpi4j.so`. However on Mac OS it will be `libpi4j.dylib` and on Windows it will be `pi4j.dll`. As a developer you should just specify the root name and allow the JVM to perform the physical mapping.